# What is the intended way do avoid flake8-bugbear's B006, i.e. mutable-default warning, in a wrapper?

Tags: python-3.x, flake8

I have a function wrapper like this

```py
def fun(arg, kwarg=None):  # in my code the function is imported from a package
    return None


def mywrap(myarg, funkwargs={"kwarg": "default"}):
    return fun(myarg, **funkwargs)
```

If I run flake8 including Bugbear, I get the B006 warning:

```
$ flake8 above_example.py 
above_example.py:5:29: B006 Do not use mutable data structures for argument defaults.  They are created during function definition time. All calls to the function reuse this one instance of that data structure, persisting changes between them.
```

In the case above, where I like to have some default settings provided to `fun`, what is the intended way to do this?

Version:

```
$ flake8 --version
3.7.9 (flake8-bugbear: 19.8.0, mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.5.0, pyflakes: 2.1.1) CPython 3.7.3 on Linux
```

#### Edit:

If the answer is "use `None`", would the following be the "proper" way?

```py
def mywrap(myarg: Any, funkwargs: Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]=None) -> None:
    """MyWrap.

    Parameters
    ----------
    myarg : Any
    funkwargs : Dict[Any, Any], Optional
        Default `{"kwarg": "default"}`.

    """
    if not funkwargs:
        funkwargs = {"kwarg": "default"}
    return fun(myarg, **funkwargs)
```

Comment: https://medium.com/python-features/how-to-avoid-classic-pitfall-while-passing-default-values-in-python-7002c0dc4c7c   Use `None` as default value instead of

Comment: to your edit: Yes, though I'd write `if funknwargs is None: ...` to differentiate between intentionally passed `funkwargs={}`

Comment: Don't use `None` as the default when the input isn't modified: it makes the code much less clear. Use an immutable mapping instead (see my answer) or silence the message (`# noqa: B006`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "right" answer is [`types.MappingProxyType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType). This creates a read-only view on the original dictionary.

```py
def mywrap(myarg, funkwargs=types.MappingProxyType({"kwarg": "default"})):
    return fun(myarg, **funkwargs)
```

Much better than using `None` as the default.

Comment: This generates a `B008`... so the answer is no good.

Comment: @EmmanuelSciara, not on my machine. I'm using flake8 v3.9.0 and flake8-bugbear v21.4.3. In fact, there's an explicit unit test for this: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8-bugbear/blob/63239e09ededc6efe841555376f288b115154953/tests/b006_b008.py#L20

Comment: Indeed, this capability has been added 6 months ago, and my version was previous to that. My bad. 
Most of the literature still points the `Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]=None` solution followed by a check in the code, but this way seems better. I wonder to which version of Python 3 it applies, though.

Comment: types.MappingProxyType was added in Python 3.3, so it's in every non-EOL version.

Comment: This looks (reads) terrible. Too verbose.